# SolrNet with Castle Windsor and basic authentication

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, basic-authentication, solrnet

I use Windsor container in purpose of SolrNet multicore access, but my Solr cores requires basic authentication. Is it possible use SolrNet Windsor intergation with authentication?

I'm tried next:

```
static SolrInteractServer()
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<ISolrConnection>().ImplementedBy<SolrConnection>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IHttpWebRequestFactory>().Eq(new WebAuthentication("login", "password"))));
    }

private static WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

public static void RegisterFacility<T>(IEnumerable<string> coreUrls, string baseHttpUrl = null)
    {
        SolrNetFacility facility = null;
        if (baseHttpUrl != null)
        {
            facility = new SolrNetFacility(baseHttpUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            facility = new SolrNetFacility();
        }
        foreach (var httpUrl in coreUrls)
        {
            var coreName = "core_" + Guid.NewGuid();
            facility.AddCore(coreName, typeof(T), httpUrl);
            RegisteredCores.Add(coreName, new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(T), httpUrl));
        }

        container.AddFacility("solr", facility);
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Type, string>> RegisteredCores = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Type, string>>();
```

When I run container.AddFacility throws:

> *Component SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection could not be registered. There is already a  component with that name. Did you want to modify the
>   existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique
>   name.*

and stack trace:

> at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Naming.DefaultNamingSubSystem.Register(IHandler
>   handler)    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.RegisterHandler(String
>   name, IHandler handler, Boolean skipRegistration)    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandlerFactory.Create(ComponentModel
>   model, Boolean isMetaHandler)    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddCustomComponent(ComponentModel
>   model, Boolean isMetaHandler)    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddCustomComponent(ComponentModel
>   model)    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration`1.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal
>   kernel)    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[]
>   registrations)    at
>   Castle.Facilities.SolrNetIntegration.SolrNetFacility.Init() in
>   g:\prg\SolrNet\Castle.Facilities.SolrNetIntegration\SolrNetFacility.cs:line
>   80    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Facilities.AbstractFacility.Castle.MicroKernel.IFacility.Init(IKernel
>   kernel, IConfiguration facilityConfig)    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(IFacility facility)    at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(String key, IFacility
>   facility)    at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.AddFacility(String
>   idInConfiguration, IFacility facility)    at
>   SolrInteractionLogic.Core.SolrInteractServer`1.RegisterFacility[T](IEnumerable`1
>   coreUrls, String baseHttpUrl) in D:\1. Job projects\1. In
>   Progress\Semantic
>   Force\Reporting\SFDigestGenerator\SolrInteractionLogic\Core\SolrInteractServer.cs:line
>   58    at SolrInteractionTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\1. Job
>   projects\1. In Progress\Semantic
>   Force\Reporting\SFDigestGenerator\SolrInteractionTest\Program.cs:line
>   26    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: @MauricioScheffer << i'm tries next: `container.Register(Component.For<ISolrConnection>().ImplementedBy<SolrConnection>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IHttpWebRequestFactory>().Eq(new WebAuthentication(login, passsword))));`and then  `container.AddFacility("solr", facility);` (where facility is previous created and configured). This code throws exception 'Already registered for SolrConnection etc. ... blah blah'. what i doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the code as part of the question. Also post the entire exception stack trace.

Comment: Where and how do you call SolrInteractServer() and RegisterFacility() ?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer << Constructor is static and as I hope is called by CLR in runtime. I only call SolrInteractServer<SFDocument>.RegisterFacility<SFDocument>(new List<string>() {somecore1, somecore2 }, somedefaultcore); at console programm start (in Main) just for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register `IHttpWebRequestFactory` in the container, not `ISolrConnection`.

Comment: << If I'll do this Windsor auto-inject registered component in SolrConnection.HttpWebRequestFactory property?

Comment: @DrAlligieri Yes, Windsor does it automatically.

Comment: OK, tried test this later - now we disable authentication for work purposes. Tnx you!

Comment: Return to auth implementation again. And this solution is right. Thank you!

Comment: The following line worked for me - 
`windsorOffersContainer.Register(Component.For<IHttpWebRequestFactory>().ImplementedBy<BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey("username").Eq("admin"), Property.ForKey(username).Eq(password)));`

Answer (score 2):

use following line to implement authentication

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISolrConnection>().ImplementedBy<SolrConnection>().Named(core1Connection).DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IHttpWebRequestFactory>().Eq(new BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory("User", "password"))).Parameters(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Parameter.ForKey("serverURL").Eq(core1url)));
```